# Wordpress ColorMag search input positioning with ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, search, filter

I'ved created a wordpress website with the colormag theme.
https://demo.themegrill.com/colormag/
I think its fairly simple and nice.

Now I want to create a search bar with custom 4 inputs fields (just below the menu)
categories (drop down), countries (drop down), datefrom and dateto

The fields are actually from ACF.

I'd like to know what should I do to create this search input ? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields

Comment: Possibly thanks, would you know roughly in wordpress colormag where to place the code for the search for right below the menu navbar?